# How can I capture a comprehensive trace on a Linux environment for a .NET application and analyze it?

Tags: .net, linux, profiling, dottrace

I have a .NET application that I can run on both Linux and Windows environments. When running it on Windows, I can analyze its behavior in real-time without stopping the application, using dotTrace for live tracing. However, as I understand, this functionality is limited on Linux.

I have tried recording a trace with the commands `dottrace attach` and `dottrace attach --profiling-type=Timeline`, but the resulting files are only a few KBs in size (instead of the expected GBs, as when recording a trace on Windows), and they throw an error when opened. I have also tried using `dotnet trace`, but I'm unsure how to open the resulting file and whether it provides the information I need.

How can I capture a comprehensive trace on a Linux environment, and what tools can I use to analyze it?